# Verify file version within installshield during build

Tags: installshield

This may be a very simple question but I couldn't find a solution. What I am trying to achieve is verify the file version of the files to be deployed  within InstallShield. If the version does not matches with a given version number, the InstallShield project will fail to build. Btw, the file version will be supplied from external source.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as a prebuild or postbuild step. For prebuild you would reflect the ISM's File table and ISPathVariable tables to determine the files InstallShield is pickign up and then check the version on those files against your external source.

For postbuild you'd reflect the MSI's File table and compare the FileVersion column to your external source.  Or, perform an admin install to extract the MSI to a directory and then reflect that structure and compare to your external source.

It's an unusual request though... in all my years I haven't needed to do this.